# Sum of hours and minutes when minutes exceeding 60 minute

Tags: sql, datetime

I have one query,but it not giving correct answer.I want to display like this 5 Hour 58 minutes + 7 Hour 58 minutes=13 hour 56 minutes (the answer should be 13.56),but this below query giving output 13.6 .
Please reply me with any other solution. (`Effort1` is 5 Hour column, `Effort1Minutes` is 58 minute column and same `Effort2` is 7 Hour column, `Effort2Minutes` is 58 minute column .

```
select SUM(Effort1 + Effort2) + SUM(Effort1Minutes + Effort2Minutes) / 60 + CONVERT(decimal(18,2), (SUM(Effort1Minutes + Effort2Minutes) % 60) / 100.00)
from TimesheetDetails
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have an hammer, every problem looks like a nail. This is a common pitfall, which basically means "use the right tool for each given problem".

Why are you using such a convoluted query to calculate a sum of times?

1. Why don't you have two `TIME` columns, which you can later add using `ADDDATE(d1, d2)`
2. Why don't you use a `TIME INTERVAL` datatype, as defined in the SQL 99 Standard?
3. Why don't you return the result in minutes, and leave the application to convert it into the format of your choosing?
4. Why don't you return separately the hours and the minutes, and once again leave the application to handle the extra hour that may arise from the sum of the minutes?

As you can see, there are plenty of other solutions that solve your issue from the root, while also granting you a better database design altogether. Please consider them, expecially the number one.

Comment: While it may be possible to get by with using `time` columns, it's still not quite the right data type. `time` is meant to represent a time of day - not a time interval. And given the OP is perfoming addition of these values, it indicates that they're meant to be intervals.

Comment: If you want to be extremely adherent to the type meanings, you can always record `Time1Start` `Time1End` and so forth, but anyway I'm not offering a concrete solution but merely a thought exercise for the reader about improving his/her database

Comment: The problem is more to do with e.g. that `time` can't accomodate a period longer than 24 hours - which a sum of intervals can easily exceed.

Comment: Visit http://www.techrepublic.com/article/master-oracles-time-interval-datatypes/ for the Time Interval Datatype in the SQL 99 standard. The link discusses Oracle. The OP Doesn't say which DBMS he's using.

Comment: @WalterMitty - true, they don't say *here* what DBMS they're using. But in the question I linked to (which was also written by the same poster, and is essentially this same problem) they specifically mention SQL Server 2008.